# Cómo agregarle texto por defecto a mi DropDownListFor

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

Acaba de salirme un error que al momento de no seleccionar un valor de mi "dropdownlistfor Sexo" se cae el sistema, y me di cuenta que el texto por defecto NO cuenta con un valor.

```
<select class="form-control" id="campo_sexo" name="sexo_Inter" disabled="">
  <option value>Seleccione su sexo</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
```

Aquí es donde coloco el valor por defecto

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sexos, "Seleccione su sexo", new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" })
```

Y aquí es lo que estuve investigando para colcocarle un valor a mi texto por defecto, pero me marca error.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sexos, new ListItem("Seleccione su sexo", string.Empty), new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" })
```

Se que puedo usar Jquery para agregarle un valor, pero quisiera saber si es posible agregarle un valor mediante la vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la propiedad `sexo_Inter` del modelo colocale el atributo `[Required]`  y en la vista en la sección de scripts agrega el jqueryval `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`. Hacer eso validará que no se envíe el formulario si está vacío el dropdownlist

Y agrega la linea `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` abajo del dropdownlist para que te muestre ahí el mensaje de error.

Por ejemplo así:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, (SelectList)ViewBag.Sexos, "Seleccione su sexo", new { @id = "campo_sexo", @class = "form-control" })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo_Inter, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   <input type="submit" value="enviar" class="btn btn-success pull-right" />
    }
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Eres el mejor amigo @crrlos ;)